# Customized segmented control in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3, uisegmentedcontrol

I would like to recreate the same effect than Pinterest:

[image]

Given that I'm new in Swift, I have three simple questions:

- Is the menu a segmented control customized? or something like buttons?
- How can I create this effect/animation of sliding? Is this a collectionView or something like that?
- And finally, is it possible to create this with storyboard or the viewController needs to be created in full code ?

Comment: You should be asking three separate questions here.

Comment: Segment control:- Customized, below control seems page view controller

Comment: 1. Buttons
2.You can use collection view or UIPageViewController.
3 . You can use storyboard or xib or custom code VC.

Comment: You might consider to take a look at those two libraries : [Material](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material#tabs) and [Motion](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Motion)

Comment: you can use segment control with two container view by playing container view width constraint you can give this animation. if you know how to play with constraints.

Comment: use this library https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit

Comment: I agree this is too broad, @ZeMoon - may I suggest a close vote?

Comment: @halfer Voted to close.

Comment: @ZeMoon how can I close?

Comment: @KevinB You can either delete the question, or it will get closed automatically when enough close votes have been cast.

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for highly customisable segmented, with colors and fonts.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var segmentedSelection = 0
    let titles = ["AA", "BB", "CC"]
    let colors = [Color.red, .green, .white]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomSegmentedControl(segmentedSelection: $segmentedSelection, titles: titles, colors: colors)
            Spacer()
            Text("Hello, selection is " + titles[segmentedSelection] )
                .padding()
        }
    }
}




struct CustomSegmentedControl: View {
    @Binding var segmentedSelection : Int
    var titles : [String]
    let colors : [Color]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack{
                ForEach(0 ..< titles.count, id: \.self){ (i: Int) in
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        print(titles[i])
                        segmentedSelection = i
                    }, label: {
                        Text(titles[i])
                            .foregroundColor(colors[i])
                            .font(.system(size: i == segmentedSelection ? 22 : 16))
                    })
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)

                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```